# multiple wildcard entries

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind

my client has around 300,000 domains and they just have a wildcard for all of them

```
* A   12.12.12.12
```

Now they want to create a sub domain that points to a different IP and still have the flexibility of wildcard, something like

```
ww1.*    A   24.24.24.24


*        A   12.12.12.12
```

Looks like in BIND, the lower "*" is catch-all and taking over every query and hence ww1 is not working.

One of solutions offered by IT folks was to create seperate 300K zones for just "ww1" and leave the "*" wildcard.

Are there any other DNS software's that can achieve this task easily?

Any other ways to deal?

Comment: I don't quite follow. You mean like "ww1.foo.mydomain.com" and "ww1.bar.mydomain.com" and so on should point to 24.24.24.24?

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is similar to this one:

[Is it possible to have regular-expression CNAME record in DNS?](https://serverfault.com/questions/133707/is-it-possible-to-have-regular-expression-cname-record-in-dns)

You basically want to pattern match the query, and return either IPAddress1 or IPAddress2, depending on how the matching goes.

As that referenced discussion goes into, you won't find this capability in standard DNS server software.  I don't know what performance will look like if you create 300K zones.  Performance may completely suck.  You may be better off writing your own DNS server that will do the pattern match that you're looking for.