# How to map a hostname to IP with custom logic?

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, bind, reverse-dns, dnsmasq

I need to resolve hostnames with the next logic:

```
r0z0n0   10.0.0.0
r10z15n120   10.10.15.120
r255z255n255   10.255.255.255
```

and so on.

I don't want to have 16,581,375 records. It is better to use a simple programming logic.

Is it possible to realize?

Comment: Why? That seems pretty pointless. You are simply using the IP address in the name. It is probably less confusing to just use the IP address. Names were meant to be used to give a host a name that is easier to understand than the address.

Comment: I simplified a question but if it is possible to resolve names with the custom logic then it opens a powerful instrument for DNS name resolution. Sometimes wildcards isn't enough. For example regular expressions would be much more powerful than just wildcards.

Comment: May be a duplicate of [this one](http://serverfault.com/questions/133707/is-it-possible-to-have-regular-expression-cname-record-in-dns)?